# Rails find Parent that has two Children with certain attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have over 100,000 objects in my database for different Product. Each Product has 4-6 Variants. Because of this, it is not easy to lazily edit large amount of data by iterating through everything. Because of this, I am trying to get only the exact number of Products I need.

So far, I can get all the Products that have a Variant with the size attribute 'SM'.

The hang up, is getting all the Products that have both a Variant with size 'MD' and 'SM'.

This is the code I am using `Product.joins(:variants).where('variants.size = ?', 'SM')`

I have tried adding `.where('variants.size = ?', 'MD')` to it, but that does work.

Comment: Can you give this a try? `Product.joins(:variants).where(variants: {size: ['SM', 'MD']}).group(:id).having('COUNT(*) = 2')`

Comment: So far, the best I have done is create `arr1` which is all Product that contains `Variant.size = 'SM'` and create `arr2` which is all Product with `Variant.size = 'MD'` and then I create `arr3 = arr1 & arr2`. I can't help but think this extremely inefficient

Comment: that returns a hash of {ids=>2}, @tbuehlmann

Answer (score 4):

How about this

```
Product.where(
 id: Variant.select(:product_id)
     .where(size: 'SM')
).where(id: Variant.select(:product_id)
    .where(size: 'MD')
)
```

This should generate something akin to

```
SELECT products.* 
FROM products 
WHERE products.id IN (SELECT 
                       variants.product_id 
                      FROM variants 
                      WHERE size = 'SM') 
AND products.id IN (SELECT 
                       variants.product_id 
                      FROM variants 
                      WHERE size = 'MD')
```

so the product id must be in both lists to be selected.

Additionally This should also work (Not 100% certain)

```
Product.where(id: Product.joins(:variants)
                 .where(variants: {size: ['SM', 'MD']})
                 .group(:id)
                 .having('COUNT(*) = 2').select(:id)
```

Which should generate something like

```
SELECT products.*
FROM products
WHERE 
 products.id IN ( SELECT products.id
                  FROM products
                  INNER JOIN variants 
                   ON variants.product_id = products.id
                  WHERE 
                    variants.size IN ('SM','MD')
                  GROUP BY 
                    products.id
                  HAVING 
                    Count(*) = 2
```

One more option

```
p_table = Products.arel_table
v_table = Variant.arel_table

sm_table = p_table.join(v_table)
           .on(v_table[:product_id].eq(p_table.[:id])
                .and(v_table[:size].eq('SM'))
           )
md_table = p_table.join(v_table)
           .on(v_table[:product_id].eq(p_table.[:id])
                 .and(v_table[:size].eq('MD'))
           )

Product.joins(sm_table.join_sources).joins(md_table.join_sources)
```

SQL

```
SELECT products.*
FROM products
INNER JOIN variants on variants.product_id = products.id
  AND variants.size = 'SM'
INNER JOIN variants on variants.product_id = products.id
  AND variants.size = 'MD'
```

These 2 joins should enforce the small and medium because of the INNER JOIN

Answer (score 2):

IMHO you need to use a bit more SQL instead of Rails magic to build database queries like that.

```
Product
  .joins('INNER JOIN variants as sm_vs ON sm_vs.product_id = products.id')
  .joins('INNER JOIN variants as md_vs ON md_vs.product_id = products.id')
  .where(sm_vs: { size: 'SM' })
  .where(md_vs: { size: 'MD' })
```

Or simplified - as @engineersmnky suggested:

```
Product
  .joins("INNER JOIN variants as sm_vs ON sm_vs.product_id = products.id AND sm_vs.size = 'SM'")
  .joins("INNER JOIN variants as md_vs ON md_vs.product_id = products.id AND sm_vs.size = 'MD'")
```

Both queries do basically the same. Just choose the version you like better.

Comment: We could skip the `where` altogether in this case and make the `size` a condition of the join e.g.  `"INNER JOIN variants as sm_vs ON sm_vs.product.id = products.id AND sm_vs.size = 'SM'"` then the joins alone will filter the list.

Comment: I tried to find a better "Rails Way" to do this, but nothing seemed to work.  The second example of filtering by joins worked great for me.

Answer (score -1):

Product.joins(:variants).where('variants.size = ? OR variants.size = ?', 'SM','MD')

Comment: That will also get products with only the size SM variant.

Comment: Ok, thank you for comment I trying to learn, since I put with OR logical for same column, my understanding it will get either SM or MD, can you explain more detail

Comment: You are right about that. As I understand the question, products with both variants are searched, having size == 'SM' and size == 'MD'.

Comment: this will return Product with variant 1 OR variant 2.  The OP requested how to return Product that associates with BOTH children, not either child.