# Turn array to comma separated strings

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a hash of an array of uuids as such

```
{ "my_uuids"=> ["uuid1", "uuid2", "uuid3"] }
```

I also have a raw SQL query to insert all uuids within the hash's array into:

```
SELECT bars.foo
FROM bars
WHERE bars.uuid IN ("uuid1", "uuid2", "uuid3")
```

I do not know how many uuid's there will be, so setting each uuid to a variable will not scale.

A string of strings does not work with mysql either (i.e. `"'uuid1', 'uuid2', 'uuid3'"`).

Comment: As a side note, unless `uuids` is a variable pointing to some object, `{ uuids => ["uuid1", "uuid2", "uuid3"] }` is not valid syntax. probably should be `{ :uuids => ["uuid1", "uuid2", "uuid3"] }`

Comment: You are right, sorry for my formatting. But you knew what I meant

Answer (score 3):

Try this one

```
Bar.where(uuid: your_hash['uuids']).select(:foo)
```

Comment: My sql query in my question is simplified, in reality I have several joins and selects which will not scale with active record

Comment: And so? You can separate each part. A string for joins and select and an hash for the where part. `Bar.joins("INNER JOIN t2 ON ...").select("id, name, etc").where(uuid: your_hash['uuids'])`

Comment: @Scap what does *"will not scale with active record"* even mean? Joins do not even have to be `String`s you can merge `Arel` joins right into an AR query and the assembly will still be correct. [Example for edification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44890594/1978251) Everything is possible if you just believe

Comment: @engineersmnky I'm a believer! thanks for linking that example

Answer (score -1):

Here is the answer I was looking for:

```
SELECT bars.foo
FROM bars
WHERE bars.uuid IN (#{myuuids.map {|str| "\"#{str}\""}.join(", ")})
```